# Bootstrap Carousel indicators not cycling in correct order

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I was trying to make the twitter bootstrap carousel work, now everything is working fine except for the indicators that are not working properly, when i press the next-arrow the indicators jumps directly to the third instead of going on the second, and when i go back by click prev-arrow the image completely disappear, where is the issue? what am i doing wrong?

In my case i got a div z-index positioned on top of the slider for achieving the effect of a block not moving on it. see it by yourself for better understanding:

Here is my example: http://jsfiddle.net/jRa5r/2/

Here is the HTML, follow up on jsfiddle for the full example with the rest of the code.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide"> <!-- slider -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="caption-block"></div>
                <div class="active item"> <!-- item 1 -->
                    <img src="img/slider1.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h4>A team with long experience in Domestic and International relationships with key sector decision-makers.</h4>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- end item -->
                <div class="item"> <!-- item 2 -->
                    <img src="img/slider1.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h4>Title</h4>
                        <p>Mollitia officia reiciendis excepturi temporibus quibusdam.</p>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- end item -->
                <div class="item"> <!-- item 3 -->
                    <img src="img/slider1.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h4>Title</h4>
                        <p>Quibusdam blanditiis.</p>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- end item -->
            </div> <!-- end carousel inner -->
            <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
            <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
        </div> <!-- end slider -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take your

```
<div class="caption-block"></div>
```

out of

```
<div class="carousel-inner"></div>
```

You will need to restyle the caption block though.
Bootstrap thinks your caption is an item maybe?

Updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jRa5r/10/

189px for the new height of the "caption-block" div is what I found to match the container.
Hope this helps!